# TypeError: this.state is undefined ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Pasar parámetros del hijo al padre y mostrarlos, me captura el evento del click, pero no sale, al ver el parámetros que recibe sale `undefined` en el lado del padre, lo que intento es que se arme un selector de objetos, las cuales se irán agregando por cada clic hecho, pero no recibe lo devuelto.

**Example**

Es la clase padre el cual tendrá todas las funcionalidades y estados de la aplicación, mediante el cual se irá pintando la APP, de la cual delego a una aplicación hijo para el listado, otro para añadir.

**Example2**

Es la clase que hereda de de la clase Padre **Example** para añadirle o capturar dato para añadir.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Example2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { txt:"" };
    }
    add2(a){
     alert(a);
     this.setState({txt:a});
     this.props.click(this.txt);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.add2.bind(this,"click")}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Example2 from './Example2';
export default class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { liked: ["txt1","txt2","txt3","txt4"] };
    }
    add(a){
        alert(a);
        var it=this.state.liked.concat(a);
        this.setState({liked:it});
    }
    del(i){
        var it=this.state.liked;
        it.splice(i,1);
        this.setState({liked:it});
    }
    render() {
        const items = this.state.liked.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={item} onClick={() => this.del(i)}>
            {item}
          </div>
        ));
        return (
            <div>
                <Example2 click={this.add}/>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                  transitionName="example"
                  transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                  transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                  {items}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Comment: De donde viene `this.txt` en el metodo `add2` de la clase `Example2` ? Creo que deberias de ir a buscarlo al estado. Ademas te falta hacer el `bind` del metodo `add` en la clase `Example`

Answer (score 0):

La manera más sencilla de evitar el reseteo (rebind) de this a las operaciones es usar el fat-arrow => para definirlas (este es el punto por el que te marca estado indefinido):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Example2 extends Component {
state = {numItems:0};
add2= () => {
   console.log("add2");
   const num = this.numItems+1; 
   this.props.click("txt"+(this.props.numItems+1));
   this.setState({numItems:num});
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick= {this.add2} >Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

También cambié un poco el manejo del estado para pasar el número actual de items, cuestión que puedes variar si gustas:

```
export default class Example extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: ["txt1","txt2","txt3","txt4"] };
}
add=(a)=>{
    var itAnt = this.state.liked;
    const it=itAnt.concat(a);
    this.setState({ liked:it});
}
del(i){
    var it=this.state.liked;
    it.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({liked:it});
}
render() {
    const items = this.updateItems(this.state.liked);
    return (
        <div>
            <Example2 click={this.add} 
                    numItems={this.state.liked.length} />
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="example"
              transitionEnterTimeout={500}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
              {items}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    );
}
updateItems(items){
    return items.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={item} onClick={() => this.del(i)}>
          {item}
        </div>
      ));
}
}
```

también separé el updateItems para no saturar el render con operaciones extra.

La manera complicada de ligar el this a las funciones de los objetos es en el constructor, como sigue:

```
export default class Example extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: ["txt1","txt2","txt3","txt4"] };
    this.handlerAdd=this.handlerAdd.bind(this);
}   
state={};
handlerAdd(a){
    console.log("add", a);
    var itAnt = this.state.liked;
    console.log("state", this.state);
    const it=itAnt.concat(a);
    this.setState({ liked:it});

};
```

esto tiene muchos contras, aunque es la manera usual. Por ejemplo, hay que poner un constructor siempre y todas las funciones que acceden a this hay que colocarlas, lo cual se puede olvidar fácilmente.